# Why can't I add several projection 3d subplots to my matplotlib animation?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I cannot add a second projection 3d axis to my figure.
If I uncomment the line of ax2, I'm getting the error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/sequoia/data1/gcheron/lib/anaconda2/envs/detectron/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/cbook/**init**.py",
>   line 388, in process
>       proxy(*args, **kwargs)   File "/sequoia/data1/gcheron/lib/anaconda2/envs/detectron/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/cbook/**init**.py",
>   line 228, in **call**
>       return mtd(*args, **kwargs)   File "/sequoia/data1/gcheron/lib/anaconda2/envs/detectron/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/animation.py",
>   line 1499, in _stop
>       self.event_source.remove_callback(self._loop_delay) AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'remove_callback'

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation
import pandas as pd


a = np.random.rand(2000, 3)*10
t = np.array([np.ones(100)*i for i in range(20)]).flatten()
df = pd.DataFrame({"time": t ,"x" : a[:,0], "y" : a[:,1], "z" : a[:,2]})


def update_graph(num):
    data=df[df['time']==num]
    graph._offsets3d = (data.x, data.y, data.z)
    title.set_text('3D Test, time={}'.format(num))


fig = plt.figure()

ax = fig.add_subplot(221, projection='3d')
#ax2 = fig.add_subplot(222, projection='3d')
title = ax.set_title('3D Test')
ax.scatter(data.x, data.y, data.z)


data=df[df['time']==0]
graph = ax.scatter(data.x, data.y, data.z)

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update_graph, 20, 
                                   interval=50, blit=True)
ani.save('motion.mp4', writer=writer)
```

If I let it comment, the code works fine and the video contains 4 subplot cells (3 are empty). Thanks!

Comment: Could you make sure that if someone tries to run your code they would actually see the error you are reporting, not some undefined variables and missing imports and missing return statement? ([mcve])

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When correcting for undefined variables, missing imports and missing return statement,

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import pandas as pd

a = np.random.rand(2000, 3)*10
t = np.array([np.ones(100)*i for i in range(20)]).flatten()
df = pd.DataFrame({"time": t ,"x" : a[:,0], "y" : a[:,1], "z" : a[:,2]})

def update_graph(num):
    data=df[df['time']==num]
    graph._offsets3d = (data.x, data.y, data.z)
    title.set_text('3D Test, time={}'.format(num))
    return graph, title

fig = plt.figure()

ax = fig.add_subplot(221, projection='3d')
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(222, projection='3d')
title = ax.set_title('3D Test')
ax.scatter(df.x, df.y, df.z)

data=df[df['time']==0]
graph = ax2.scatter(data.x, data.y, data.z)

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update_graph, 20, 
                                   interval=50, blit=True)
ani.save('motion.gif', writer="imagemagick")
plt.show()
```

the animation looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Actually, I have restarted my jupyter kernel and I had no longer this error... I think there was a conflict with some plt configuration. Sorry about the variables (there were defined in another cell).